# How can I compute the SHA512/256 hash in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sha512, cryptokit

I'm familiar with CryptoKit and the SHA512 implementation, which is super easy to use.

```
let digest = SHA512.hash(data: Data("".utf8))
```

However, I can't seem to find how to compute *SHA512/256* (the truncated version of SHA512) anywhere in the Apple CryptoKit documentation. Do I somehow have to combine `SHA512` with `SHA256Digest`?

Comment: "I can't seem to find how to compute SHA512/256 anywhere" What do you mean? Isn't that exactly what your snippet is demonstrating?

Comment: This is computing a digest using the `SHA512` algo, but I'm looking for the `SHA512/256` algo, it's distinct from `SHA512`.

Comment: Oh interesting. I'd suggest clarifying those details into the question, for others not-in-the-know

Comment: CryptoKit is pretty limited in what it offers. I don't know anything common that offers SHA512/256; I would probably look at adapting CryptoSwift. https://cryptoswift.io

Comment: Apple's `CryptoKit` does not implement such algorithm. This'll leave you with the provided libraries (answer and comment) or NaCL maybe, or you can write your own implementation

Answer (score 1):

I think this pod will do the trick.

This has the implementation for SHA512/SHA256. (Check readme's HASH section: SHA-2)

Link: [SHA512/SHA256 Lead](https://github.com/mlachmish/Cryptography)

Comment: I did check out this library and found it to be outdated in terms of the Swift code it's using. I was looking for a CryptoKit solution, if one exists.

Comment: @MorganWilde For all you know the answer is ‘it doesn’t’ (though sure, it would be nice to write so explicitly), so why not accept an alternative package?